# My car revs high when pulling away to pick up speed and starting changing gears

Tags: troubleshooting

My vw mk 1 carburettor revs high when pulling away and picking up speed and changing gears what could be worng?

Comment: Carburettors don't rev.  Can you explain the symptoms a little clearer.  Does the car have an automatic transmission?

Comment: Yes it do got a automatic transmission, im driving a 2005 vw citi chico golf the carburettor model, whenever i pull away from a stop my car as i starting to pick up speed and change gears the revs goes high like to 3000 revs and the car does not sound normal, and i do change the gears and step on the clutch on the same time in sequance, and the car is already heated up, my car didnt make that sound ever